# Consistent text line in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, console-application

I'm creating a small text-based game in VB.NET and want to have a constant line of text across the top of the screen.
I want any new text that appears, such as when you progress further through the game to appear below the status bar and not remove it from view.

For example

```
I = Inventory M = Menu E = Exit
Something to do with the game
Something else to do with the game
```

When  you progress, I want to status bar to remain at the top of the screen

Example

```
I = Inventory M = Menu E = Exit
Something else to do with the game
Something further to do with the game
```

Any advice on how I could acheive this?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe try your output to start with a  clear screen then menu, then constant, then ...

Answer (score 1):

If you look closely at the Console Class there is a [`CursorTop`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.cursortop(v=vs.110).aspx) Property which can be used to set the line that you are writing to. The top line will be 0, just avoid writing to that line if you are not wanting to change it. Here is a quick and dirty example of what I am talking about

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim x As Integer
        Console.CursorTop = 0
        Console.WriteLine("I = Inventory M = Menu E = Exit")
        For x = 1 To 100
            WriteDataToConsole("Action #" + x.ToString(), x)   
        Next
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

    Sub WriteDataToConsole(text As String, pos As Integer)
        Dim temp As Integer
        If pos > 20 Then
            temp = (pos Mod 21) + 1
            Console.CursorTop = temp
        Else
            Console.CursorTop = pos
        End If
         Console.WriteLine(text)
    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Thanks Mark, wasn't sure exactly what way to go about doing it. I'll test that in the game and see if it works for me :)

Comment: You may need to change the logic a bit to make it fit. I just used some  arbitrary limits

Answer (score 0):

Have your menu in one string and your scrollable data in another then when writing to the screen concatenate them.

Example:

```
MenuString = "I = Inventory M = Menu E = Exit"
GameString = "Something to do with the game"
GameString = GameString & vblf & "Something else to do with the game"
GameString = GameString & vblf & "Something further to do with the game"
TextBox1.Text = MenuString & vblf & GameString
```

Comment: I don't think this will work in a console application.